# How do I retrieve the "animated" duration of various iOS method calls?

Tags: ios, animation, duration

Many iOS setters have an "animated" variation, like `setZoomScale:` on `UIScrollView`, or, well, anything that has an `animated:` parameter.

My question is, a) How do I determine what duration is being used, and b) If necessary, how do I modify that duration?

Comment: [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:2.0];

Comment: do you want to do this for only certain types of objects, or any & all objects that take an "`animated:`" parameter?

Comment: I guess ideally to be able to set it case by case. Different speeds will feel better or worse for different situations.

Comment: @Tutankhamen I just tried this: `[UIView setAnimationDuration:30.0]; [self.scroller setZoomScale:scale animated:YES];` (using 30 seconds, to make sure the effect is noticeable for this test). No luck :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question. From my experience, those durations do vary depending on the platform (iPad vs. iPhone) and are not documented or in any way accessible. A very common duration for many system animations seems to be around 0.35-0.40 seconds. Shorter animations often are exactly half that time. Longer animations often are exactly twice that time.

The rotation animation triggered by reorienting the device for example uses 0.4s when rotating landscape towards portrait (or vice versa) but 0.8s when rotating landscape left to landscape right (or portrait down to portrait up).

There are however exceptions. The keyboard show animation for example is offering its duration within the notification triggered. It is not modifiable but at least you can read it.

Comment: Yeah, the keyboard reveal/hide is the one exception I can think of that actually exposes its duration. For most other cases though, it seems as though we have to just make a best guess.

Comment: Accepting this answer because - although it's not what I want to hear - it seems to be this is about as close as we're going to get, for now. __"We can't know for sure, and we can't change it."__ Oh well.